# Seleccion de mútiples lineas en VsCode

Tags: json, vscode, configuración

Me gustaría seleccionar el contenido de varias lineas de VsCode. Actualmente lo tengo de la manera que aparece en la siguiente imagen, se me crean múltiples cursores en varias lineas cuando pulso `ctrl` + `shift` + `flecha` no sé si hay algun lugar que se pueda ayudar en el `settings.json` de VsCode. ¿Me podrían ayudar?

[image: Ejemplo]

Comment: Debieras poder cambiar ese comportamiento en el menú `Selection -> Switch to Alt+Click for multi cursor` (o el equivalente en tu instalación en español)

Comment: @César Lozano   Cual es tu objetivo?, que resultado esperas?

Comment: ¿Shift + flecha?